# jQueryUI - Full Page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

We need to create a full page HTML/Javascript app (100% HEIGHT/WIDTH) that does not scroll, we are using **jQueryUI**. Is there a way in jQuery to enforce this?

The goal is to put 2 tab bars which each are 50% height and stay that proportion regardless of screen size.

Here's a example of what we mean by full page app which we created using another framework (DevExpress):

http://BahaiResearch.com/

We have to use jQuery because the app will be **100% client without any network connections**. DevExpress is a server-side framework mostly. As such, performance is not critical, there is no network latency so a big and simple framework is better than a complex custom one for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't need **any** jQuery to get (100% height/width) - (scrolling). CSS is the way to go here:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.tabBar {
    height: 49.1%;
    overflow: scroll;
    border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

Markup:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="tabBar">Tab bar 1</div>
        <div class="tabBar">Tab bar 2</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[jsfiddle demo ⇒](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/5ypPH/)

I would recommend starting with a CSS reset of some variety. I like [the one from YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssreset/). That way, you can remove the `padding: 0;` and `margin: 0;` properties, and don't run into any other unexpected styles that uglify up your layout.

---

That said, if you're looking to get fancy with the layout, YUI provides a nice [layout builder](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/grids/builder/) - again, you really only need CSS for the basics.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the JQuery 'UI.Layout' plugin: http://layout.jquery-dev.net/index.cfm

This mimics Java's 'BorderLayout' and is simple yet has a lot of features. Much easier than messing about with CSS for hours ;)